# mySQL table loses column structure when exported as CSV format

Tags: mysql, database, raspberry-pi, mariadb, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a table from MariaDB to a folder in CSV format. In MariaDB program, I entered the query: `MariaDB [testdatabase]> SELECT * from datatable into outfile '/tmp/exportf.csv';` I then managed to locate this exported file. However, on opening the csv file with Excel, I find that the data are all clustered onto one column. These should be organised into 7 columns. How can I modify my query to avoid this issue?
[image: onecolumnissue]

Comment: try this SELECT * from datatable into outfile '/tmp/exportf.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;

Comment: Thanks Sameera, that solves the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT * from datatable into outfile '/tmp/exportf.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
```